# IE opens two popups instead of one

Tags: php, javascript, internet-explorer-9

I have a complex PHP script that reads in some information and then calls a bash script to process it. The PHP script shows the output in a pop-up window and then navigates the browser back to the page from where it was called.

So it works in Firefox and in Chrome but something strange happens in IE 9. When I click on the button that calls the PHP script, the browser gets blank, shows two identical empty popups one behind the other and when the information is populated in one of them the browser navigates back and closes the other popup. This is the code:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'win1 = window.open("", "", "status = 0, height=800, width=1000, resizable=1, scrollbars=1");';
echo 'window.history.go(-1);';
echo "win1.document.write($content);";
echo "win1.document.close();";
echo '</script>';
```

Why does it show two popups and how can I prevent that?

Answer (score 2):

Why is the window.history.go not at the end?

Also remove all spaces in the parameters and give a name (second parm) without spaces.

Lastly if you use a submit button change it to button or if a link, return false in the onclick

Try

```
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var win1 = window.open("", "mywin", "height=800,width=1000,resizable,scrollbars");
if (win1) {
  win1.document.write($content);
  win1.document.close();
  window.history.go(-1);
}
</script>
```

[DEMO TO TRY TO REPRODUCE](http://plungjan.name/test/reply1.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I rewrote it this way but the second window still appears.

Comment: Do you have a URL or can you create a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net) of the rendered html/js? - or at least show the code that calls the page

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a url - this is a new project that is not published yet. The interesting part is that both popups don't appear at the same time. The second one comes 1-2 seconds later and disappears when the browser navigates back. It takes the browser about 5 secs to complete the whole operation.

Comment: Just tested it on the new IE. Still the same thing.

Comment: I cannot help you without the complete code - the button and an example of the php return code

Comment: The button is <input type="submit" value="Click me!"> and it is within a <form> so it runs the php script which takes some values from the form and processes them by running them through a bash script on the server. Then it echoes the JavaScript. The output can be an empty string.

Comment: Does the form have a target or does the page have a `base target` tag?

Comment: No, neither has base target tag.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19094/discussion-between-mplungjan-and-regeduser00x)